# Has Batman ever said he hates the Joker?

Tags: dc, batman, the-joker

One of the running gags in the Lego Batman movie is that Batman never said he hated the Joker, and Lego Joker is very upset by this. Based on what little Batman continuity I am familiar with, this seems accurate (at least until [the end of the Lego Batman movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHXwi5Mz7ug&feature=youtu.be&t=3m9s)).

In the regular (non-Lego) DC continuities, is it true that Batman never once said he hates the Joker?

Comment: -1: Google -> image search -> `batman joker hate`.

Comment: Worthy of an acceptance?

Answer (score 85):

> [image]
> <sub><sup>[Batman Vol.2 #17](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_2_17)</sup></sub>
>
> *"I **HATE** nothing more on this Earth than you, Joker. **Nothing"***

Comment: Six minutes? You're slacking!

Comment: @corsiKa - It took me twenty seconds to find the pic and six minutes and forty seconds to find out which comic it was from :-)

Comment: Well, it just says he hates nothing *more* than Joker. But maybe he doesn't hate anything, not even Joker. Yet somehow the expression conveys it.

Comment: I agree with @DepressedDaniel. Much more likely.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel: or maybe he hates everything, but equally.

Comment: Maybe he's a robot without emotion.

Comment: @SandyChapman he would be batbot then.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel - Batman hates other things; http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-zQFjS_5heQw/TW60i5x5xyI/AAAAAAAABgI/ozPSR9ISAXw/s1600/BA36%2B-%2Bhate%2Byou.jpg

Comment: I'm surprised that's not the Frank Miller Batman, where he nearly kills Joker (and Joker suicides due to his injuries). Also, Batman [hates chocolate](http://img03.deviantart.net/f1f2/i/2009/243/e/5/what_batman_hate_by_nickgold.jpg)

Comment: @Machavity So we know Batman hates the Joker at least as much as he hates ice cream.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel - Batman is essentially a very proactive misanthrope.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Indeed, "doesn't hate anything" is just a special case of the more general "hates everything equally". (0 = 0)

Comment: I am not a comics fan but from what I know it would be natural for Batman to hate the Joker.

Comment: @Valorum Six minutes forty seconds? [Now why does that sound so familiar?](https://www.reddit.com/r/deathnote/comments/4lfcbu/why_6_minutes_and_40_seconds/)